# Remote debug container in kubernetes using intellij

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, kubernetes

I try to remote debug the application in attached mode with host: `192.168.99.100` and port `5005`, but it tells me that it is `unable to open the debugger port`. The IP is `192.268.99.100` (the cluster is hosted locally via minikube).

Output of `kubectl describe service catalogservice`

```
Name:                     catalogservice
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=catalogservice
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.98.238.198
Port:                     web  31003/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 web  31003/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.6:8080
Port:                     debug  5005/TCP
TargetPort:               5005/TCP
NodePort:                 debug  32003/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.6:5005
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

This is the pods service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: catalogservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: catalogservice
  ports:
  - name: web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 31003
    nodePort: 31003
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: debug
    protocol: TCP 
    port: 5005
    nodePort: 32003
    targetPort: 5005
```

And in here I expose the containers port

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: catalogservice
    image: elps/myimage
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: app
    - containerPort: 5005
      name: debug
```

The way I build the image:

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
ADD /target/catalogservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar catalogservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n", "-jar", "catalogservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When I execute `nmap -p 5005 192.168.99.100` I receive

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5005/tcp closed avt-profile-2
```

When I execute `nmap -p 32003 192.168.99.100` I receive

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
32003/tcp closed unknown
```

When I execute `nmap -p 31003 192.168.99.100` I receive

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
31003/tcp open unknown
```

When I execute `kubectl get services` I receive

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
catalogservice    NodePort    10.108.195.102   <none>        31003:31003/TCP,5005:32003/TCP   14m
```

`minikube service customerservice --url` returns

```
http://192.168.99.100:32004
```

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to using a `NodePort` in a `Service` you could also use [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) to access the debug port in your `Pod`.

> `kubectl port-forward` allows using resource name, such as a pod name, to select a matching pod to port forward to since Kubernetes v1.10.

You need to expose the debug port in the Deployment yaml for the Pod

```
spec:
  containers:
    ...
    ports:
      ...
      - containerPort: 5005
```

Then get the name of your Pod via

```
kubectl get pods
```

and then add a port-forwarding to that Pod

```
kubectl port-forward podname 5005:5005
```

In IntelliJ you will be able to connect to

Host: `localhost`

Port: `5005`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/kubernetes-debugging) Intellij plugin.
Also, if you use [Fabric8](https://fabric8.io/), it provides the [`fabric8:debug`](https://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:debug) goal.

Comment: Cloud Code IntelliJ plugin does the job for me. Isn't Fabric8 library discontinued?

Answer (score 0):

There was a slip in the yaml you first posted as:

```
    - containerPort: 5050
      name: debug
```

Should be:

```
    - containerPort: 5005
      name: debug
```

You also need to use the external port of `32003` when configuring the IntelliJ debugger. With those changes it should work.

You may also want to think about how to make it more flexible. In the past [when I've done this](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-query/pull/6) I've used a different [form for the docker start command](https://github.com/Activiti/example-runtime-bundle/blob/782b290fd92f89b5aec5631b792939855c792d6c/Dockerfile#L18) that allows you to turn remote debug on and off by an environment variable called `REMOTE_DEBUG`, which for you would be:

`CMD if [ "x$REMOTE_DEBUG" = "xfalse" ] ; then java $JAVA_OPTS -jar catalogservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ; else java $JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n -jar catalogservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ; fi`

You'll probably find you want to [set the env var](https://github.com/Activiti/example-runtime-bundle/blob/d7d1f531cdb1890d4d1b4dd40829d84ce503d17f/charts/runtime-bundle/values.yaml#L40) `$JAVA_OPTS` to limit jvm memory use to avoid [issues in k8s](https://dzone.com/articles/why-my-java-application-is-oomkilled).

Comment: Oops! Still doesn't work, so edited the correct port above.

Comment: @elp I think you're trying to attach the debugger process to the wrong port. `5005` is the internal port but the intelliJ debugger needs to link to the external port, which is `32003`

Comment: I nmapped `32003` as well and is it closed too :| Attached some more information above. I also tried to change the port in intellij 5005 -> 32003 but I got the same result.

Comment: Are you able to try starting just that container with `docker run` and exposing ports (e.g. with `-p`) and seeing if you can remote debug like that? Just to narrow down at what level the problem is.

Comment: You could also try port-forwarding like in http://blog.christianposta.com/kubernetes/java-remote-debug-for-applications-running-in-kubernetes/

Comment: Need to change lots of placeholders set by the cluster so I can do it later on. Portfowarding does not work either.. I attached the output of the `service description` above btw, probably something is wrong with my ip?

Comment: Presumably you can also try `localhost`?

Comment: I already tried but that would not make any sense anyway as the cluster runs via minikube, which means it runs on a different IP.

Comment: You need to allow the debug agent to accept from any host.  Specify the address to "address=*:5005", otherwise it will only allow access from 127.0.0.1.  Once you have this setup try remote connecting to the pod using the node Port you specified which is 32003 from intellij.